# Reading textfiles from path in a text file [PHP]

Tags: php, file

I have a textfile ($file) that contains the path to other files. My goal is to read the content of those files and print it in a table. When reading the paths from $file, **only the last line path works correctly.**

```
<?php
    $file = "log2.txt";
    if(file_exists($file)) {            
        $handler = fopen($file,'r');
        while(!feof($handler)) {
            $lines = fgets($handler);
            $wordarray = explode(' ', $lines);
            #echo $wordarray[0]." ".$wordarray[1]." ".$wordarray[2];
            if (strpos($lines, 'NOK') !== false) {
                echo "<tr><td>".$wordarray[0]."</td></tr>";
                if(file_exists($wordarray[2])){
                    $log = fopen($wordarray[2], 'r');
                    #echo "FILE EXISTS ".$log;
                    $logtext = fread($log,filesize($wordarray[2]));
                    echo "<tr><td>".$logtext."</td></tr>";
                    fclose($log);
                } else {
                    echo "<tr><td>"."FILE ".$wordarray[2]." FAILED TO LOAD"."</td></tr>";
                }
            }                
        }
        fclose($handler);
    } else {
        echo "FILE DOES NOT EXISTS";
    }
?>
```

Here is an exemple of how log2.txt would look like:

```
POE NOK poelog.txt
LINK-ERRORS OK OK
LATENCIES NOK latencieslog.txt
VOLATILE NOK volatilelog.txt
```

I think that the problem could be about line endings or so, but cannot get the point.

Comment: Do these other files i.e. `poelog.txt & latencieslog.txt` etc all exist in the same folder as this script and `log2.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. The `$wordarray[2]` contains also new line character so before using it pass it through `trim()` function and store it in a variable (`$filename` in my case).

Updated inner `if`:

```
if (strpos($lines, 'NOK') !== false) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$wordarray[0]."</td></tr>";
    $filename = trim($wordarray[2]);

    if (file_exists($filename)){
        echo "FILE EXISTS ".$filename;
        $log = fopen($filename, 'r');
        $logtext = fread($log, filesize($filename));
        echo "<tr><td>".$logtext."</td></tr>";
        fclose($log);
    }
    else{
        echo "<tr><td>"."FILE ".$filename." FAILED TO LOAD"."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This short function works like a sharm:

```
function displayFileContent( $fileName )
{
    $arrayWithFileNames = file ( $fileName );
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ( $arrayWithFileNames as $singleFileName )
    {
        # remove the trailing \n on Linux - windows has 2 character as EOL
        $singleFileName = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $singleFileName));
        $contentOfFile = file_get_contents( $singleFileName );
        echo  "<tr><td>{$contentOfFile}</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

You use it like this:

> `displayFileContent ("path-to-your-file");`

Remark: There is no check if the file does exist....